# Navigate to a new page after Onbording with React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

**Case:**
This is my Swipper component, where i create and render all of the logic for a Onboarding screen that leads to a HomeScreen. I'm trying now to add navigation to it and got cought in some errors I can't figure out.

**Expected Result**
After the 3rd Onboarding screen has been shown, the "Star Now" button should navigate to a HomeScreen.

**Actual Result**
After pressing the button on the 3rd screen, I get the following error message:
 *Can't find variable: navigate*

I'm running it on Expo, here is the link if you wanna try it out.
https://expo.io/@jfsene/onboarding

```
/**
 * Swiper
 * Renders a swipable set of screens passed as children,
 * pagination indicators and a button to swipe through screens
 * or to get out of the flow when the last screen is reached
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,       // Detects screen dimensions
  Platform,         // Detects platform running the app
  ScrollView,       // Handles navigation between screens
  StyleSheet,       // CSS-like styles
  View,             // Container component
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 
import Button from '../components/Button';
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import Screens from "../screens/Screens";

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

// Detect screen width and height
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class OnboardingScreens extends Component {

  // Props for ScrollView component
  static defaultProps = {
    // Arrange screens horizontally
    horizontal: true,
    // Scroll exactly to the next screen, instead of continous scrolling
    pagingEnabled: true,
    // Hide all scroll indicators
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
    // Do not bounce when the end is reached
    bounces: false,
    // Do not scroll to top when the status bar is tapped
    scrollsToTop: false,
    // Remove offscreen child views
    removeClippedSubviews: true,
    // Do not adjust content behind nav-, tab- or toolbars automatically
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets: false,
    // Fisrt is screen is active
    index: 0
  };

  state = this.initState(this.props);

  /**
   * Initialize the state
   */
  initState(props) {

    // Get the total number of slides passed as children
    const total = props.children ? props.children.length || 1 : 0,
      // Current index
      index = total > 1 ? Math.min(props.index, total - 1) : 0,
      // Current offset
      offset = width * index;

    const state = {
      total,
      index,
      offset,
      width,
      height,
    };

    // Component internals as a class property,
    // and not state to avoid component re-renders when updated
    this.internals = {
      isScrolling: false,
      offset
    };

    return state;
  }

  /**
   * Scroll begin handler
   * @param {object} e native event
   */
  onScrollBegin = e => {
    // Update internal isScrolling state
    this.internals.isScrolling = true;
  }

  /**
   * Scroll end handler
   * @param {object} e native event
   */
  onScrollEnd = e => {
    // Update internal isScrolling state
    this.internals.isScrolling = false;

    // Update index
    this.updateIndex(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset
      ? e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
      // When scrolled with .scrollTo() on Android there is no contentOffset
      : e.nativeEvent.position * this.state.width
    );
  }

  /*
   * Drag end handler
   * @param {object} e native event
   */
  onScrollEndDrag = e => {
    const { contentOffset: { x: newOffset } } = e.nativeEvent,
      { children } = this.props,
      { index } = this.state,
      { offset } = this.internals;

    // Update internal isScrolling state
    // if swiped right on the last slide
    // or left on the first one
    if (offset === newOffset &&
      (index === 0 || index === children.length - 1)) {
      this.internals.isScrolling = false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Update index after scroll
   * @param {object} offset content offset
   */
  updateIndex = (offset) => {
    const state = this.state,
      diff = offset - this.internals.offset,
      step = state.width;
    let index = state.index;

    // Do nothing if offset didn't change
    if (!diff) {
      return;
    }

    // Make sure index is always an integer
    index = parseInt(index + Math.round(diff / step), 10);

    // Update internal offset
    this.internals.offset = offset;
    // Update index in the state
    this.setState({
      index
    });
  }

  /**
   * Swipe one slide forward
   */

  navigate = () => {
     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
     return;
  }
  swipe = () => {
    // Ignore if already scrolling or if there is less than 2 slides
    if (this.internals.isScrolling || this.state.total < 2) {
      return;
    }

    const state = this.state,
      diff = this.state.index + 1,
      x = diff * state.width,
      y = 0;

    // Call scrollTo on scrollView component to perform the swipe
    this.scrollView && this.scrollView.scrollTo({ x, y, animated: true });

    // Update internal scroll state
    this.internals.isScrolling = true;

    // Trigger onScrollEnd manually on android
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      setImmediate(() => {
        this.onScrollEnd({
          nativeEvent: {
            position: diff
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }

  /**
   * Render ScrollView component
   * @param {array} slides to swipe through
   */
  renderScrollView = pages => {
    return (
      <ScrollView ref={component => { this.scrollView = component; }}
        {...this.props}
        contentContainerStyle={[styles.wrapper, this.props.style]}
        onScrollBeginDrag={this.onScrollBegin}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onScrollEnd}
        onScrollEndDrag={this.onScrollEndDrag}
      >
        {pages.map((page, i) =>
          // Render each slide inside a View
          <View style={[styles.fullScreen, styles.slide]} key={i}>
            {page}
          </View>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  /**
   * Render pagination indicators
   */
  renderPagination = () => {
    if (this.state.total <= 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const ActiveDot = <View style={[styles.dot, styles.activeDot]} />,
      Dot = <View style={styles.dot} />;

    let dots = [];

    for (let key = 0; key < this.state.total; key++) {
      dots.push(key === this.state.index
        // Active dot
        ? React.cloneElement(ActiveDot, { key })
        // Other dots
        : React.cloneElement(Dot, { key })
      );
    }

    return (
      <View
        pointerEvents="none"
        style={[styles.pagination, styles.fullScreen]}
      >
        {dots}
      </View>
    );
  }

  /**
   * Render Continue or Done button
   */
  renderButton = () => {
    const lastScreen = this.state.index === this.state.total - 1;
    return (
      <View pointerEvents="box-none" style={[styles.buttonWrapper, styles.fullScreen]}>
        {lastScreen
          // Show this button on the last screen
          // TODO: Add a handler that would send a user to your app after onboarding is complete
          ? <Button text="Start Now" onPress={() => navigate('Home')} />
          // Or this one otherwise
          : <Button text="Continue" onPress={() => this.swipe()} />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }

  /**
   * Render the component
   */

  render = ({ children } = this.props) => {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.fullScreen]}>
        {/* Render screens */}
        {this.renderScrollView(children)}
        {/* Render pagination */}
        {this.renderPagination()}
        {/* Render Continue or Done button */}
        {this.renderButton()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // Set width and height to the screen size
  fullScreen: {
    width: width,
    height: height
  },
  // Main container
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  // Slide
  slide: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  // Pagination indicators
  pagination: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 110,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  // Pagination dot
  dot: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
    width: 8,
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
    marginLeft: 3,
    marginRight: 3,
    marginTop: 3,
    marginBottom: 3
  },
  // Active dot
  activeDot: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  // Button wrapper
  buttonWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 40,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
});
```

Comment: Please show more StackNavigator from your code to see your navigation structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a prop for navigation

```js
/**
 * Swiper
 * Renders a swipable set of screens passed as children,
 * pagination indicators and a button to swipe through screens
 * or to get out of the flow when the last screen is reached
 */

import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions, // Detects screen dimensions
  Platform, // Detects platform running the app
  ScrollView, // Handles navigation between screens
  StyleSheet, // CSS-like styles
  View, // Container component
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from './Button';


// Detect screen width and height
const {
  width,
  height
} = Dimensions.get('window');


export default class Swiper extends Component {

  // Props for ScrollView component
  static defaultProps = {

    //Here is what you need
    onPressnav: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

    // Arrange screens horizontally
    horizontal: true,
    // Scroll exactly to the next screen, instead of continous scrolling
    pagingEnabled: true,
    // Hide all scroll indicators
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
    // Do not bounce when the end is reached
    bounces: false,
    // Do not scroll to top when the status bar is tapped
    scrollsToTop: false,
    // Remove offscreen child views
    removeClippedSubviews: true,
    // Do not adjust content behind nav-, tab- or toolbars automatically
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets: false,
    // Fisrt is screen is active
    index: 0
  };

  state = this.initState(this.props);

  /**
   * Initialize the state
   */
  initState(props) {

    //const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
    // Get the total number of slides passed as children
    const total = props.children ? props.children.length || 1 : 0,
      // Current index
      index = total > 1 ? Math.min(props.index, total - 1) : 0,
      // Current offset
      offset = width * index;



    const state = {
      total,
      index,
      offset,
      width,
      height,
    };

    // Component internals as a class property,
    // and not state to avoid component re-renders when updated
    this.internals = {
      isScrolling: false,
      offset
    };

    return state;
  }

  /**
   * Scroll begin handler
   * @param {object} e native event
   */
  onScrollBegin = e => {
    // Update internal isScrolling state
    this.internals.isScrolling = true;
  }

  /**
   * Scroll end handler
   * @param {object} e native event
   */
  onScrollEnd = e => {
    // Update internal isScrolling state
    this.internals.isScrolling = false;

    // Update index
    this.updateIndex(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset ?
      e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
      // When scrolled with .scrollTo() on Android there is no contentOffset
      :
      e.nativeEvent.position * this.state.width
    );
  }

  /*
   * Drag end handler
   * @param {object} e native event
   */
  onScrollEndDrag = e => {
    const {
      contentOffset: {
        x: newOffset
      }
    } = e.nativeEvent, {
      children
    } = this.props, {
      index
    } = this.state, {
      offset
    } = this.internals;

    // Update internal isScrolling state
    // if swiped right on the last slide
    // or left on the first one
    if (offset === newOffset &&
      (index === 0 || index === children.length - 1)) {
      this.internals.isScrolling = false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Update index after scroll
   * @param {object} offset content offset
   */
  updateIndex = (offset) => {
    const state = this.state,
      diff = offset - this.internals.offset,
      step = state.width;
    let index = state.index;

    // Do nothing if offset didn't change
    if (!diff) {
      return;
    }

    // Make sure index is always an integer
    index = parseInt(index + Math.round(diff / step), 10);

    // Update internal offset
    this.internals.offset = offset;
    // Update index in the state
    this.setState({
      index
    });
  }

  navigatet = () => {
    console.log('This has been Clicked');

  }

  /**
   * Swipe one slide forward
   */
  swipe = () => {
    // Ignore if already scrolling or if there is less than 2 slides
    if (this.internals.isScrolling || this.state.total < 2) {
      return;
    }

    const state = this.state,
      diff = this.state.index + 1,
      x = diff * state.width,
      y = 0;

    // Call scrollTo on scrollView component to perform the swipe
    this.scrollView && this.scrollView.scrollTo({
      x,
      y,
      animated: true
    });

    // Update internal scroll state
    this.internals.isScrolling = true;

    // Trigger onScrollEnd manually on android
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      setImmediate(() => {
        this.onScrollEnd({
          nativeEvent: {
            position: diff
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }

  /**
   * Render ScrollView component
   * @param {array} slides to swipe through
   */
  renderScrollView = pages => {
    return ( <
      ScrollView ref = {
        component => {
          this.scrollView = component;
        }
      } { ...this.props
      }
      contentContainerStyle = {
        [styles.wrapper, this.props.style]
      }
      onScrollBeginDrag = {
        this.onScrollBegin
      }
      onMomentumScrollEnd = {
        this.onScrollEnd
      }
      onScrollEndDrag = {
        this.onScrollEndDrag
      } >
      {
        pages.map((page, i) =>
          // Render each slide inside a View
          <
          View style = {
            [styles.fullScreen, styles.slide]
          }
          key = {
            i
          } > {
            page
          } <
          /View>
        )
      } <
      /ScrollView>
    );
  }

  /**
   * Render pagination indicators
   */
  renderPagination = () => {
    if (this.state.total <= 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const ActiveDot = < View style = {
      [styles.dot, styles.activeDot]
    }
    />,
    Dot = < View style = {
      styles.dot
    }
    />;

    let dots = [];

    for (let key = 0; key < this.state.total; key++) {
      dots.push(key === this.state.index
        // Active dot
        ?
        React.cloneElement(ActiveDot, {
          key
        })
        // Other dots
        :
        React.cloneElement(Dot, {
          key
        })
      );
    }

    return ( <
      View pointerEvents = "none"
      style = {
        [styles.pagination, styles.fullScreen]
      } >
      {
        dots
      } <
      /View>
    );
  }

  /**
   * Render Continue or Done button
   */
  renderButton = () => {
    navigation = this.props.navigation
    const lastScreen = this.state.index === this.state.total - 1;
    return ( <
      View pointerEvents = "box-none"
      style = {
        [styles.buttonWrapper, styles.fullScreen]
      } > {
        lastScreen
        // Show this button on the last screen
        // TODO: Add a handler that would send a user to your app after onboarding is complete
        ?
        < Button text = "Start Now"
        onPress = {
          this.props.onPressnav
        }
        />
        // Or this one otherwise
        :
          < Button text = "Continue"
        onPress = {
          () => this.swipe()
        }
        />
      } <
      /View>
    );
  }

  /**
   * Render the component
   */
  render = ({
    children
  } = this.props) => {

    return ( <
      View style = {
        [styles.container, styles.fullScreen]
      } > { /* Render screens */ } {
        this.renderScrollView(children)
      } { /* Render pagination */ } {
        this.renderPagination()
      } { /* Render Continue or Done button */ } {
        this.renderButton()
      } <
      /View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // Set width and height to the screen size
  fullScreen: {
    width: width,
    height: height
  },
  // Main container
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  // Slide
  slide: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  // Pagination indicators
  pagination: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 110,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  // Pagination dot
  dot: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
    width: 8,
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
    marginLeft: 3,
    marginRight: 3,
    marginTop: 3,
    marginBottom: 3
  },
  // Active dot
  activeDot: {
    backgroundColor: '#5FD7F4',
  },
  // Button wrapper
  buttonWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 40,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to HomeScreen from OnboardingScreens, OnboardingScreens should be added in StackNavigator as well.